# project.json vs csproj adding packages

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2017

My question is how to specifically search for asp.net core packages to add to my projects.  I was using the project.json file fluently.  So far my experience with csproj and `nuget` and getting the specific .net core package is that it is cumbersome.

For example, I can search for entityframework and the list will include many packages and extensions but not the `entityframeworkcore` package. I can search the `nuget` website and use the tags option which assists, but this really seems like a step backwards from the ease of project.json. Is there a simple trick that I am missing? Ideally, I would like to be able to use `nuget` commands from command line, pull back packages with a keyword like entityframework, and filter the list of returned packages to those specific to .net core

https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Tags%3A%22Core%22

Comment: Key words won't work it has to be exact for PMC Install-Package command. There is no short cutting it.   `Microsoft.AspNetCore.` will show every package AspNetCore it will even include those that are deprecated and no longer valid.  Right Click -> Edit your project file and you will how the structure of the file has changed with csproj.

Comment: This question isn't relevant to this tag. It would be more appropriately tagged in visual studio 2017.

Comment: Intellisense doesnt work for me in .csproj that was one of the main things that I liked about project.json.